# MySQL latest version for Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: mysql

This is my OS Detail and I want to use latest version of MySQL which version should I prefer?

axt@root:~$ cat /etc/os-release

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

axt@root:~$ hostnamectl

```
Static hostname: axt
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Kernel: Linux 4.15.13-x86_64-linode106
Architecture: x86_64
```

Comment: Try 8 - some nifty new features. If that fails, just work your  way back. Don't forget MariaDB and Percona!

Comment: Thanks @Vérace but when I checked in https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/  mysql 8 only available for Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (x86, 64-bit) and above. not for Ubuntu 14.04.2

Comment: Compile it yourself maybe?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 was released 4 years ago; MySQL 5.6 was released 5 years ago.  But, probably it does not matter.